# Keep getting NULL when updatingtonewlocation

Tags: ios, null, cllocationmanager

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

NSString *latitude =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *longitude =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:newLocation.timestamp];

resultsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@ Location %.06f %.06f %@", ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) ? @"bg" : @"fg", resultsLabel.tag == 0 ? @"gps:" : @"sig" , newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude, [formatter stringFromDate:newLocation.timestamp]];

NSLog(@"%@", resultsLabel.text);

LocationTestAppDelegate * appDelegate = (LocationTestAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate log:resultsLabel.text];




}
```

But i get this as output.

```
(null)
```

on :

```
       NSLog(@"%@", resultsLabel.text);
```

Does anyone know what im doing wrong?

```
  - (id) initWithLabel:(UILabel*)label
{
resultsLabel = label;
return [super init];
}
```

And in my delegate i set the resultLabel here:

```
- (void) log:(NSString*)msg
{
 NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString * logMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]], msg];
NSString * fileName = [self locationPath];
FILE * f = fopen([fileName UTF8String], "at");
fprintf(f, "%s\n", [logMessage UTF8String]);
fclose (f);}
```

**EDIT**

I deleted the GPS functionality.

Does anyone know how a proper NSLog would be in the newlocation. longitude latitude timestamp?

**EDIT 2**

I set the resultlabel here:

```
@interface  LocationDelegate : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> 
{
UILabel * resultsLabel;
NSString * _phonenumber;


}

- (id) initWithLabel:(UILabel*)label;
//-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
//-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)aName;
//-(NSDictionary *)toDictionary;

@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *phonenumber;
```

Comment: How do you initialize your resultsLabel? Check if it if NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Your `init` code is strange. This is more usual:

```
- (id) initWithLabel:(UILabel*)label
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        resultsLabel = label; // Or maybe _resultsLabel, depending on your code
    }
    return self;
}
```

And then access what I presume is an instance variable through `self.resultsLabel`.

Presumably your problem is that `resultsLabel` is already `nil` when you try to set it's text. Sending a message to `nil` does nothing, not even give an error.

Comment: I set it here:  UILabel * resultsLabel;

Comment: Where do i check whether resultsLabel = nil?

Comment: `NSLog(@"Results Label: %@", resultsLabel)`, wherever you want to actually use the label.

Comment: You should probably be creating the results label in `viewDidLoad`, or using Interface Builder and connecting an outlet.